# How to access Tag property

Tags: delphi

How can I access `HTTPRIO.Tag` previously assigned from, for instance, the `HTTPRIO.OnBeforeExecute` event? Is it possible?

Let's say I have something like this:

```
procedure TForm1.HTTPRIO1BeforeExecute(const MethodName: string; SOAPRequest: TStream);
begin
  if THHPRIO(Sender).Tag = 99 then
    ...some code...
end;
```

But I don't have a `Sender` on any of the `THTTPRIO` events.

Comment: Not it is not. I'm creating an HTTPRIO component for each request. And even so I couldn't do like that, because Sender do not exist on event execute.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are assigning events to multiple `THTTPRIO` objects, but don't have access to a `Sender` parameter in the events (bad design on `THTTPRIO`'s author), one workaround is to use the [`TMethod` record](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.TMethod) to manipulate the event handler's `Self` pointer to point at the `THTTPRIO` object rather than the `TForm1` object, eg:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  M: TBeforeExecuteEvent;
begin
  M := HTTPRIOBeforeExecute;
  TMethod(M).Data := HTTPRIO1;
  HTTPRIO1.OnBeforeExecute := M;

  M := HTTPRIOBeforeExecute;
  TMethod(M).Data := HTTPRIO2;
  HTTPRIO2.OnBeforeExecute := M;

  // and so on ...
end;
```

And then you can type-cast `Self` inside the events, eg:

```
procedure TForm1.HTTPRIOBeforeExecute(const MethodName: string; SOAPRequest: TStream);
begin
  if THTTPRIO(Self).Tag = 99 then
    ...some code...
end;
```

Alternatively, you can use a standalone procedure (or `class static` method) with an explicit parameter for the `Self` pointer, eg:

```
procedure HTTPRIOBeforeExecute(Sender: THTTPRIO; const MethodName: string; SOAPRequest: TStream);
begin
  if Sender.Tag = 99 then
    ...some code...
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  M: TBeforeExecuteEvent;
begin
  TMethod(M).Data := HTTPRIO1;
  TMethod(M).Code := @HTTPRIOBeforeExecute;
  HTTPRIO1.OnBeforeExecute := M;

  TMethod(M).Data := HTTPRIO2;
  TMethod(M).Code := @HTTPRIOBeforeExecute;
  HTTPRIO2.OnBeforeExecute := M;

  // and so on ...
end;
```

Comment: That's a hack (not saying it is bad, though)!

Comment: It is a hack, certainly. But it is an officially supported hack, and one that is very direct and doesn't involve any other external tracking.

Comment: First sugestion works like a charm. Thanks Remy. Thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 0):

While Remy's solution works, leaving the code in `TForm1` leaves you at risk of accidentally referencing fields from `TForm1` in `TForm1.HTTPRIOBeforeExecute`, and since "Self" isn't a TForm1 anymore, that would crash/corrupt memory.

I would personally use the following approach :

```
THTTPRIOMethodHolder = class(THTTPRIO)
public
  procedure HTTPRIOBeforeExecute(const MethodName: string; SOAPRequest: TStream);
end;

procedure THTTPRIOMethodHolder.HTTPRIOBeforeExecute(const MethodName: string; SOAPRequest: TStream);
begin
  if {self.}Tag = 99 then
    ...some code...
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  HTTPRIO1.OnBeforeExecute := THTTPRIOMethodHolder(HTTPRIO1).HTTPRIOBeforeExecute;
  HTTPRIO2.OnBeforeExecute := THTTPRIOMethodHolder(HTTPRIO2).HTTPRIOBeforeExecute;
end;
```

This should work as long as you don't add fields in `THTTPRIOMethodHolder` and `HTTPRIOBeforeExecute` is not made virtual.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I actualy not leaving the code in TForm1.
I'm doing something like this:

```
type
  THTTPRIO_EventHandlers_v2 = Class
    procedure HTTPRIOBeforeExecute(const MethodName: String; SOAPRequest: TStream);
    procedure HTTPRIOAfterExecute(const MethodName: string; SOAPResponse: TStream);
  end;
    
  type
    THTTPRIOBeforeExecute = procedure(const MethodName: String; SPRequest: TStream) of Object;
      THTTPRIOAfterExecute = procedure(const MethodName: string; SOAPResponse: TStream) of Object;
    
  var
    HTTPRIO: THTTPRIO;
    
  procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject)
  var
    RIO_Events: THTTPRIO_EventHandlers_v2;
    EvtHTTPRIOBeforeExecute: THTTPRIOBeforeExecute;
    EvtHTTPRIOAfterExecute: THTTPRIOAfterExecute;
  begin
    HTTPRIO := THTTPRIO.Create(Application);
    HTTPRIO.Tag := 99;
    HTTPRIO.Converter.Encoding := 'utf-8';
    
    RIO_Events := THTTPRIO_EventHandlers_v2.Create;
    
    EvtHTTPRIOBeforeExecute := RIO_Events.HTTPRIOBeforeExecute;
    TMethod(EvtHTTPRIOBeforeExecute).Data := HTTPRIO;
    HTTPRIO.OnBeforeExecute := EvtHTTPRIOBeforeExecute;
    
    EvtHTTPRIOAfterExecute := RIO_Events.HTTPRIOAfterExecute;
    TMethod(EvtHTTPRIOAfterExecute).Data := HTTPRIO;
    HTTPRIO.OnAfterExecute := EvtHTTPRIOAfterExecute;
    
    RIO_Events.Free;
  end;
```

And on the, for instance, HTTPRIOBeforeExecute procedure, I'm doing this:

```
procedure THTTPRIO_EventHandlers_v2.HTTPRIOBeforeExecute(const MethodName: String; SOAPRequest: TStream);
var
  HttpRioTag: Integer;
begin
  HttpRioTag := THTTPRIO(Self).Tag;
  if HttpRioTag = 99 then
    ...some code...
end;
```

This is working as expected.
Am I doing it the right way?
Thanks

Comment: You don't really need to create the `THTTPRIO_EventHandlers_v2`. You could just use `EvtHTTPRIOBeforeExecute := THTTPRIO_EventHandlers_v2(nil).HTTPRIOBeforeExecute;` (or even `EvtHTTPRIOBeforeExecute := THTTPRIO_EventHandlers_v2(HTTPRIO).HTTPRIOBeforeExecute;`  and forget about `TMethod(EvtHTTPRIOBeforeExecute).Data := HTTPRIO;`at that point...)